# Memcached not returning stored data properly codeigniter 3

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, memcached, rethinkdb

I'm using memcached to store some data from the messages on a bot, and then later store it into a rethindkb table.
I have the code i wrote for storing below, there is also a function for retrieving the data.

On first the first step(case 0) of the preparing data method, i create an array such as this

```
`[id = 123]`
```

and store it in memcached
On the second step(case 1) of the method, i retrieve the stored data and then append another element to the data, it looks like this

```
[id = 123, lang = english]
```

On getPrepData function, i retrieve this data, in order to retrieve the value of a key from the stored stored array. However, when i retrieve the data and store it in a log, the lang key is not set and it looks like this

```
[id = 123]
```

For debugging purposes, after storing the lang key, i fetched the data from memcached and logged it and i got the desired output.
Using php 7 and codeigniter 3.

Anyone know why this happens and how i can fix it?

```
    <?php
class User extends CI_Model {
  private $data;
  private $prep_data;
  public function __construct(){

  }

  public function is_registered($id){
    require_once('application/third_party/rdb/rdb.php');
    $this->load->config('redb.php');
    $db = $this->config->item('redbdb');
    $con = r\connect(array('host' => 'localhost','db' => $db));
    $results = r\table('users')->filter(['tid' => $id])->count()->run($con);
    if($results == 0){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  public function register_prep($id,$step,$store=null){
    $this->load->driver('cache');

    switch($step){
      case(0):
      //Insert empty cache entry
      $x = $this->cache->memcached->get('prep_'.$id);
      if($x){
        $this->cache->memcached->delete('prep_'.$id);
      }
      $prep = ['tid' => $id];
      $this->cache->memcached->save('prep_'.$id,$prep,0);
      break;

      case(1):
      //insert language
      $prep = $this->cache->memcached->get('prep_'.$id);
      $prep['lang'] = $store;
      $this->cache->memcached->delete('prep_'.$id);
      $this->cache->memcached->save('prep_'.$id,$prep,0);
      $x = $this->cache->memcached->get('prep_'.$id);
      log_message('error','saved data on step 1 is : '.print_r($x,true));
      break;

      case(2):
      //Insert driver/passenger
      $prep = $this->cache->memcached->get('prep_'.$id);
      $prep['type'] = $store;
      $this->cache->memcached->save('prep_'.$id,$prep,0);
      break;

      case(3):
      //Insert contact
      $prep = $this->cache->memcached->get('prep_'.$id);
      $prep['contact'] = $store;
      $this->cache->memcached->save('prep_'.$id,$prep,0);
      break;

      case(4):
      //Finish
      $prep = $this->cache->memcached->get('prep_'.$id);
      //Insert to database
      require_once('application/third_party/rdb/rdb.php');
        $this->load->config('redb.php');
        $db = $this->config->item('redbdb');
        $con = r\connect(array('host' => 'localhost','db' => $db));
      r\table('users')->insert($prep)->run($con);
      //Delete from cache
      $this->cache->memcached->delete('prep_'.$id);
      break;
    }
  }

  public function getPrepdata($id,$var){
    $this->load->driver('cache');
    $x = $this->cache->memcached->get('prep_'.$id);
    log_message('error','fetched prep data is : '.print_r($x,true));
    return $x[$var];
  }
```

}

Answer (score -2):

you can try this example:

```
$data = array(id => 123);
if(empty($data)){
  $data = array(); // Declaring array
}
print_r($data);
```

result:
array(
    id => 123
)

now add this:

```
$new_data = array(lang => english);

array_push($data,$new_data); // Items will be add to array

print_r($data);
```

array(
    id => 123,
    lang => english
)

you want get only id number:

```
echo $data['id'];
```